# Select attribute of another attribute of entity

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, jpql

Currently I have three entities `Country`, `Office` and User, where `Country.gov` is of type `Office` and where `Office.holder` is of type `User`. Country is the owning side in `Country.gov` and Office is the owning side of `Office.holder`.

Now I want to get `Country.gov` with a `LEFT JOIN` on `Office.holder` using an attribute of Country, e.g.
`SELECT c.gov o FROM Country c LEFT JOIN FETCH c.gov LEFT JOIN FETCH c.gov.holder WHERE c.countryKey = :countryKey`, but this does not work, it throws an exception:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list 
[FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=null,role=dev.teamnight.game.entities.Country.gov,tableName=office,tableAlias=office1_,origin=country country0_,columns={country0_.gov_id,className=dev.teamnight.game.entities.Office}}] 
[SELECT c.gov FROM dev.teamnight.game.entities.Country c LEFT JOIN FETCH c.gov LEFT JOIN FETCH c.gov.holder WHERE c.countryKey = :countryKey]
```

Comment: I found a solution using `SELECT o FROM Office o LEFT JOIN FETCH o.holder LEFT JOIN FETCH Country c ON c.gov = o WHERE c.countryKey = :countryKey`. Maybe someone can explain why this works and if I can make this better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify a bit your query:

```java
List<Office> calls = entityManager.createQuery(
    "select o " +
    "from Country c " +
    "join c.gov o " +
    "left join fetch o.holder " +
    "where c.countryKey = :countryKey ", Office.class )
.setParameter( "countryKey", countryKey )
.getResultList();
```

For additional explanation, see [this section](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-explicit-join) of hibernate documentation.